# Solution theory of Poisson problem with complex zero-order term

Tags: elliptic-equations, poissons-equation

We assume that $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is a bounded open set with smooth boundary and study the PDE
$$
-\Delta u + \alpha u = f
$$
with, say, zero Dirichlet boundary conditions along $\partial\Omega$. Here, $\alpha \in \mathbb C$.

*I would like to understand the (weak) solution theory for different values of $\alpha$, in the context of Sobolev spaces.*

We already know that the second-order differential operator has a positive discrete spectrum.

- When $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ and $\alpha > 0$, then we can apply Lax-Milgram.
- When $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ and $\alpha < 0$ is not in the negative of an eigenvalue, then the solution can be found in the literature as well.

**But what happens, generally speaking, when $\alpha$ has a non-zero imaginary part? What are the essential techniques to prove the existence and uniqueness of the solution and its stability in the data?**

The Poisson problem only serves as a model problem for more generally elliptic equations.

Comment: The Fredholm alternative completely answers this question; the point is just that $-\Delta$ is self-adjoint, its spectrum is real.